# Making two textviews with different font sizes have independent lines

Tags: android-layout

I just started android app programming, so this might be a very dumb question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

I want to have two textviews next to each other, where one shows three lines in a small font and the other contains a number in a very big font (which is as big as the three lines of the other textview). What now happens is that the first line of the textview with the smaller font sizes is aligned to the line of the other textview on the base line. So, I get some whitespace above the first line, because the font size is much smaller, and the three lines don't fit because so much space is wasted.

My code looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/historytextviewId"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countertextViewId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="60sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What I want is that the left textview just acts as if the other textview had the same font size.

**EDIT:** For some reason, replacing `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` by `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` in the first `TextView` worked for me (which I tried because I found some almost completely unrelated question where that was the answer), but I still don't get why that works.

Comment: make it 0dp in android:layout_width="0dp" amd add wt

Comment: @keshav i'm sorry, what am I supposed to add?

Comment: this in second tv  android:layout_weight="1"

Comment: also use android:lines, android:max:lines attributes